# Close the mobile menu in id links

Tags: javascript

This is the mobile menu I wrote for my site.

Sometimes some links are id. (Example: herf="#id")

I want the menu to be closed automatically when the user clicks when there are such links. (Close the hamburger icon as well.)

In JavaScript, can you tell me what to do?

```js
/* eslint-env browser */
(function() {
  'use strict';
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    let hamburger = document.querySelector('.js-hamburger');
    let hamburgerMenu = function () {
      document.querySelector('.js-navs').classList.toggle('is-open');
    };
    if (hamburger) {
      hamburger.addEventListener('click', hamburgerMenu, false);
    }

   });
 })();
```

```html
<link href="https://restaurant-landing.surge.sh/styles/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="o-section c-section--header" style="background-image: none;">
      <div class="o-section__wrapper">
        <div class="c-header">
          <div class="c-header__col">

            <div class="c-hamburger">
              <input class="c-hamburger__checkbox js-hamburger" type="checkbox" aria-label="Menu" />
              <span class="c-hamburger__icon"></span>
              <span class="c-hamburger__icon"></span>
              <span class="c-hamburger__icon"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="c-header__col">
            <div class="c-header__wrap js-navs">
              <ul class="s-nav">
                <li>
                  <a href="#why-us" title="WHY US">WHY US</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#menu" title="MENU">MENU</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#popular-dishes" title="POPULAR DISHES">POPULAR DISHES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#book" title="BOOK">BOOK</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#contact" title="CONTACT">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
/* eslint-env browser */
(function() {
  'use strict';
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    let hamburger = document.querySelector('.js-hamburger');
    let hamburgerMenu = function () {
      document.querySelector('.js-navs').classList.toggle('is-open');
    };
    if (hamburger) {
      hamburger.addEventListener('click', hamburgerMenu, false);
    };
    $(".s-nav a").each((indx,link) => {
      if(link.hash.startsWith("#")) link.addEventListener("click",hamburgerMenu);
    });
   });
 })();
```

```html
<link href="https://restaurant-landing.surge.sh/styles/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="o-section c-section--header" style="background-image: none;">
      <div class="o-section__wrapper">
        <div class="c-header">
          <div class="c-header__col">

            <div class="c-hamburger">
              <input class="c-hamburger__checkbox js-hamburger" type="checkbox" aria-label="Menu" />
              <span class="c-hamburger__icon"></span>
              <span class="c-hamburger__icon"></span>
              <span class="c-hamburger__icon"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="c-header__col">
            <div class="c-header__wrap js-navs">
              <ul class="s-nav">
                <li>
                  <a href="#why-us" title="WHY US">WHY US</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#menu" title="MENU">MENU</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#popular-dishes" title="POPULAR DISHES">POPULAR DISHES</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#book" title="BOOK">BOOK</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#contact" title="CONTACT">CONTACT</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But one problem: when the menu is closed, the hamburger icon remains open.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick:

```js
const hashLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.s-nav a');
hashLinks.forEach((element) => {
    if(element.hash[0] == '#') {
        element.addEventListener('click', hamburgerMenu);
    }
});
```

How it works:

- gets all the links inside your menu
- iterates over each element
- if the element's link has a hashtag as the first character
- assign a click event listener to toggle the menu

Comment: Why not `document.querySelectorAll('.s-nav a');`?

Comment: Thanks, this is true. There is a problem here that was closed by clicking on the menu link, but the hamburger icon remains open.

Comment: @Joshua Smart Do you know what I should do about this?